# Difference between @Named and @Model

Tags: jakarta-ee, java-ee-7

What is the difference between `javax.enterprise.inject.Model` and `javax.inject.Named` ? Both are available from JSF EL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@Model` is just a shortcut for a  `@RequestScoped @Named` 
(in other words `@model` is a *stereotype* which incorporates other annotations more about stereotypes [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkhqc.html))

therefore

```
@Model
public class MainBean {
//...
```

is equal to

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class MainBean {
//...
```